# Split Directory with dots and hyphen

Tags: tcl

I want to split this path so that I have the directory name as a variable. But he is interrupted.

path to splitt:

```
/home/user/T.A.T.E.-ano_ays-(ff-A-a)-ownage
```

code:

```
bind pub "-|-" !aaa pub:aaa
proc pub:aaa { nick uhost hand chan arg } {

    set checkpath "/home/user/T.A.T.E.-ano_ays-(ff-A-a)-ownage"
    set dirname [file rootname [file tail $checkpath]]
    putnow "PRIVMSG $chan :dirname $dirname"
}
```

output:

```
dirname T.A.T.E
```

correct would be:
dirname T.A.T.E.-ano_ays-(ff-A-a)-ownage

How can fix the output from dirname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [`file split`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.html#M35) was made for:

```
% lindex [file split /home/user/T.A.T.E.-ano_ays-(ff-A-a)-ownage] end
T.A.T.E.-ano_ays-(ff-A-a)-ownage
```

`file tail` without postprocessing via `file rootname` would also work:

```
% file tail /home/user/T.A.T.E.-ano_ays-(ff-A-a)-ownage
T.A.T.E.-ano_ays-(ff-A-a)-ownage
```

`file rootname` cuts the trailing filepath component at (not including) the last dot `.`.